# integrate a scroll bar along with chartjs-zoom-plugin

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using chartjs to make graphs and for zoom. I have used its official zoom-plugin, but the problem is when we zoom in the points on charts goes beyond the axis until we zoom out. So I want to know is it possible to integrate the scroll bar along with chart zoom?

Like if the point exceeds the page width we have an automatic scroll option to scroll and see that points?

This is my canvas HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-9 chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper" id="crm_chart">
    <canvas id="graph_crm_main_panel0" width="2520" height="1130"">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOGL&ei=U7dAWaiYOc3Eepq5j5AL) is what i want to achieve

Comment: Are you able to achieve this?

Comment: @AnubhavGupta No i was not able to achieve this and at that time zoom plugin was not able to zoom properly in the general types of data . Dont know much about today.

Answer (score 0):

The provided example might not be reliable for a demo. As for the problem itself, the zoom-plugin has a drag/pan option that can be used to mode data around after it gets pushed out of view.

`zoom: {
  enabled: true, // Boolean to enable zooming
  drag: true // Enable drag-to-zoom behavior
}`